# Routing programmatically to other component using relative path in Angular2/4

Tags: angular, routes

This is my folder structure:

```
App
   -KitchenComponent
      -css
      -html
      -kitchen.component.ts
   -BedroomComponent
      -css
      -html
      -kitchen.component.ts
app.component.html
app.component.ts
```

I want to move from kitchen component to bedroom component programmatically using relative path.

```
 KitchenComponent.html
 <button (click)="moveToBedroomComponent()"></button>

KithcenComponent.ts
Constructor(private router: Router){}
moveToBedroomComponent(){
   this.router.navigate(['bedroom'], {relativeTo:_____});
}
```

I think I'm stuck in giving the relative path here, inputs are appreciated.

Comment: hey, is there anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45453582/2545680)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`relativeTo` parameter takes the reference to the activated route:

```
@Component({...})
class KitchenCmp {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
  }

  moveToBedroomComponent(){
     this.router.navigate('../bedroom', {relativeTo:this.route});
  }
}
```

Comment: Max, the moment you insert '../' it becomes absolute path, right?

Comment: @MichaelPhilips, no, it's a relative path to the current route

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it would be good to see your `app.route.ts` file.

I do navigation like that:
`this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);`

My `app.route.ts` contains `{path: 'dashboard', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}`

Also make sure your import is correct:
`import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';`

## edit

Are you sure you need `relativeTo` bit in your `router`? On the first glance it seems you don't.